# Java calculate group by passed amount

Tags: java, math

I am optimizing my old project and I'm not sure what's the best way to optimize the code below, basically, this code determines groupId (return value), by a number of points that user has, is there any better way of returning this number under those circumstances?

My Code:

```
    if(points > 1000000) {
        return 9;
    }
    if (points > 400000) {
        return 8;
    }
    if (points > 100000) {
        return 7;
    }
    if (points > 20000) {
        return 6;
    }
    if (points > 5000) {
        return 5;
    }
    if(points > 1000) {
        return 4;
    }
    if(points > 250) {
        return 3;
    }
    if(points > 25) {
        return 2;
    }
    if(points > 10) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `HashMap<Integer,Integer>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Arrays.binarySearch(int[] a, int key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-int:A-int-) like this:

```java
private static final int[] LEVELS = { 10, 25, 250, 1000, 5000, 20000, 100000, 400000, 1000000 };

static int determineGroup(int points) {
    int group = Arrays.binarySearch(LEVELS, points);
    return (group >= 0 ? group : -group - 1);
}
```

Comment: it only work with  operator equal to, the question use operator more than

Comment: @LêHoàngDững I fully tested it. That code returns the exact same values as the code in the question. E.g. for input 250, `binarySearch` returns 2 since the value is at index 2, so `(group >= 0 ? group : ...)` returns 2. For input 251, `binarySearch` return -4 *(because the value should be inserted at index 3; read the linked javadoc to understand how that works)*, and `(group >= 0 ? ... : -group - 1)` returns 3. 250 -> 2, 251 -> 3, exactly like the code in the question.